# Get slack user's access token pragmatically to send direct message using chat.postMessage

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, slack, slack-api

**Scenario**:

1. One user(also registered in slack) sharing some message from my web application to other users on my application. Now that message should also go under direct message section on behalf of the user in slack app to notify other users on slack.
2. I used https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage. I want to fetch access token available in slack app for the user that is registered in my web application using same email so that i can use this token with above chat.postMessage(with as_user = true) api.

**Arguments for chat.postMessage** will be,

**token**: xxxxxx (fetch from slack using nodejs async call(using slack email or some extra credentials))

**text**: xxxxx  (message to be shared)

**as_user**: true  (on behalf of user (using access token))

If anyone needs more details please add comment.

Comment: I need sender's access token from slack app pragmatically. Something like,doing login or providing required credentials from code getting access token in return so that i can use this token with chat.postMessage.

Comment: https://api.slack.com/docs/sign-in-with-slack I ealready forgot how to do that though since it has been some time ago since I've tinkered with Slack Oauth

Comment: This solution needs redirect url to redirect. I dont think i can get access token in nodejs